# How to solve a certain coupled first order PDE system

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to find the solution $(U,V)\equiv (U(x,t),V(x,t))$ of the following system.

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+(a+b x)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}-(c+k_1)U+k_1V=0, \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(a+b x)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}-(c+k_2)V+k_2 U=0, \\
\end{array}\right.
t\in [s,T]
\end{equation}

with the boundary conditions (where $W$ could be $U$ and $V$)

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 W(x,t)=0 \ \ \text{as} \ \ x\to-\infty,\\
 W(x,t)\to e^x \ \ \text{as} \ \ x\to\infty,\\
W(x,T)=\max \{ e^x-100,0\}
\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

Assuming that above system has a unique solution, $(U,V)$, how can I find that solution. I would be satisfied to given a reference to a paper from which I can learn a method to solve it.

Can *Mathematica* solve this system?

**Added after I got the answer from the above system:** when I modified the codes of bbgodfrey to solve the followin system :

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+(\textbf{a}_1+b x)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}-(c+k_1)U+k_1V=0, \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(\textbf{a}_2+b x)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}-(c+k_2)V+k_2 U=0, \\
\end{array}\right.
t\in [s,T]
\end{equation}

when I run the program, Mathematican seems runs out of memory. Is there any way to fix this issues or this is because Mathematica cannot solve the new system ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please write your equations in Mathematica format.  Also, what have you tried?  DSolve, perhaps?

Comment: I haven't actually tried it (would prefer to have you type the code first). But you can probably get a general solution and then adjust the integration constants to satisfy the boundary conditions as a second step. So yes, *Mathematica* can probably do it, but you should show what you have tried first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant `c` can be eliminated from the equations by a standard transformation.

```
eq1 = (Unevaluated[D[u[x, t], t] + (a + b x) D[u[x, t], x] - (c + k1) u[x, t] + k1 v[x, t]]
    /. {u[x, t] -> uu[x, t] E^(c t), v[x, t] -> vv[x, t] E^(c t)})/E^(c t) // Simplify
(* -(k1*uu[x, t]) + k1*vv[x, t] + Derivative[0, 1][uu][x, t] + 
   a*Derivative[1, 0][uu][x, t] + b*x*Derivative[1, 0][uu][x, t] *)
```

and similarly for the second expression, designated `eq2`.  Taking the difference between these two expressions yields

```
Collect[(eq1 - eq2) // Simplify, {a + b x, k1 + k2}, Simplify]
(* (k1 + k2)*(-uu[x, t] + vv[x, t]) + Derivative[0, 1][uu][x, t] - Derivative[0, 1][vv][x, t]
    + (a + b*x)*(Derivative[1, 0][uu][x, t] - Derivative[1, 0][vv][x, t]) *)
```

which can be rewritten as

```
-((k1 + k2)*zz[x, t]) + Derivative[0, 1][zz][x, t] + (a + b*x)*Derivative[1, 0][zz][x, t]
```

where `zz == uu - vv`.  And, this equation can be solved

```
First@DSolve[% == 0, zz[x, t], {x, t}]
(* {zz[x, t] -> (a + b*x)^(k1/b + k2/b) C[1][(b t - Log[a + b x])/b]} *)
```

Undoing the original transformation then yields

```
First@Solve[% /. Rule -> Equal /. zz[x, t] -> z[x, t] E^(-c t), z[x, t]]
{* {z[x, t] -> E^(c t) (a + b*x)^(k1/b + k2/b) C[1][(b t - Log[a + b x])/b]} *)
```

Note that `C[1]` is an arbitrary function of `(b t - Log[a + b x])/b`, which can be chosen to satisfy the boundary conditions in `x`.

**Alternative, Simpler Approach**

`DSolve` cannot integrate the two equations as written in the question.  However, the equations can be separated, after which `DSolve` can integrate them without difficulty.

```
r0 = First@Solve[{z[x, t] == u[x, t] - v[x, t], 
  y[x, t] == u[x, t] + v[x, t] k1/k2}, {u[x, t], v[x, t]}];
eq1 = (Unevaluated[D[u[x, t], t] + (a + b x) D[u[x, t], x] - (c + k1) u[x, t] + 
  k1 v[x, t]] /. %) // Simplify;
eq2 = (Unevaluated[D[v[x, t], t] + (a + b x) D[v[x, t], x] - (c + k2) v[x, t] + 
  k2 u[x, t]] /. %%) // Simplify;

Simplify[eq1 - eq2];
r1 = Simplify[#] & /@ DSolve[% == 0, z[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]]
(* z[x, t] -> (a + b x)^((c + k1 + k2)/b) C[1][t - Log[a + b x]/b] *)

Simplify[eq1 + eq2 k1/k2];
r2 = Simplify[#] & /@ DSolve[% == 0, y[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> C[2]
(* y[x, t] -> (a + b x)^(c/b) C[2][t - Log[a + b x]/b] *)

r0 /. {r1, r2}
(* {u[x, t] -> -((-k1 (a + b x)^((c + k1 + k2)/b)
  C[1][t - Log[a + b x]/b] - k2 (a + b x)^(c/b) C[2][t - Log[a + b x]/b])/(k1 + k2)), 
    v[x, t] -> -((k2 (a + b x)^((c + k1 + k2)/b) 
  C[1][t - Log[a + b x]/b] - k2 (a + b x)^(c/b) C[2][t - Log[a + b x]/b])/(k1 + k2))} *)
```

Note that the solution contains two arbitrary functions `C[1]` and `C[2]` of `(b t - Log[a + b x])/b`, as it must, because the original equations form a second order system of advective equations.

Note also that the earlier, incomplete solution would eventually have reached the same point.

Comment: thanks SO MUCH ! YOU are awesome : ))

Comment: @DaveNguyen  You are welcome.  However, I have a much simpler approach, which I shall add to my answer in a few minutes.  Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your work ! I truly appreciate it !

Comment: Dear bbgodfrey,
When I changed my system to 
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+(a_2+b x)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}-(c+k_1)U+k_1V=0, \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(a_2+b x)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}-(c+k_2)V+k_2 U=0, \\
\end{array}\right.
t\in [s,T]
\end{equation}

I modified your code to run it, Mathematica is just run out of memory . I would like to ask is there any way to fix this problem ? Thanks you !

Comment: @DaveNguyen  Having `a1` and `a2` different is a much harder problem, and I do not believe that it is still possible to separate the system into two uncoupled equations.  I suggest that you wait until Monday and then ask a new question in order to get the most responses.  Certainly, I shall take a hard look at it, but I am not optimistic about obtaining a closed form solution.  As an alternative, have you considered a numerical solution in a bounded region of `x`?

Comment: Dear BBgodfrey , thank you so much for replying me. I really appreciate your time on this ! 
I just currious if i change to 

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+(\textbf{a}_1)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}-(c+k_1)U+k_1V=0, \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(\textbf{a}_2)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}-(c+k_2)V+k_2 U=0, \\
\end{array}\right.
t\in [s,T]
\end{equation} ?

Comment: @DaveNguyen  This change makes the problem much easier, because all the coefficients are constant.  You might try the following.  First, simply try to solve the two equations as is with `DSolve`.  If unsuccessful, convert the two first order equations into one second order equation and try again.  If that does not work, assume that the dependent variable in the second order PDE is a product of a function of `t` only and a function of `x` only.  Certainly that will be true, allowing an eigenvalue solution.  One way or another, this last set of equations should be solvable analytically.

Comment: Dear   bbgodfrey, 
Thanks for your comments ! I appreciate it. You must be a very wonderful teacher/advisor. I will try it out to see what happens. Have a great weekend.

Comment: @DaveNguyen Still another way to address this problem is to assume `u=u0 Exp[d1 t + d2 x` and `v = v0 Exp[d1 t + d2 x`.  Plugging these into into the two differential equations leads to two algebraic equations for the constants `u0` and `v0`, which has a solution, if the determinant vanishes.  The determinant is a function of the two constants `d1` and `d2`.  Therefor, and pair `d1` and `d2` that cause the determinant to vanish is a solution. to your PDE.  So is a sum of such exponential solutions.  This solves the equations in your comment as a series of exponentials.

Comment: @DaveNguyen Moreover, a transformation of the independent variable `x` in the second set of equations in your question will change it into something like the set of equations in your comment, so it can be solved analytically in the same way.  I am not saying, of course, that the solution will be convenient to use.

Comment: Thanks so much  bbgodfrey : ) have a wonderful evening.