# Solving a second order coupled PDE system

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

This is similar to [How to solve a certain coupled first order PDE system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87963/how-to-solve-a-certain-coupled-first-order-pde-system?rq=1) but I seem to be getting errors which is most likely due to my misunderstanding on how the code is actually working. (I'm really bad at coding)

I have taken 2 different approaches to the problem, one is using the method from the link above, the other is using code I wrote. The problem with the linked code, is that I do not know how to add my boundary and initial conditions.

The system I would like to solve is as follows, where $U=U(x,t);V=V(x,t)$

$a \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = b \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2} +cV \exp(-\frac{1}{U})$

$d \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + e\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = f \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} - g V \exp(-\frac{1}{U})$

where $a-g$ and $U_0,V_0$ are constants to be decided later.

The i.cs and b.cs for the system are:

$x=0 : \frac{\partial V(0,t)}{\partial x}=0 , \frac{\partial U(0,t)}{\partial x}=0  $

$x=1 : \frac{\partial V(1,t)}{\partial x}= V-V_0 , \frac{\partial U(1,t)}{\partial x}=U-U_0  $

$t=0 : V(x,0)=V_0,U(x,0)=U_0$

Firstly, My code is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global'*"]
System = {a D[U[x, t], t] == b D[U[x, t], x, x] + c V[x, t]*Exp[-1/U[x, t]],
  d D[V[x, t], t] + e D[V[x, t], x] == 
   f D[V[x, t], x, x] - g V[x, t]*Exp[-1/U[x, t]], D[V[0, t], x] == 0, 
  D[V[1, t], x] == V[x,t]-v, D[U[0, t], x] == 0, D[U[1, t], x] == U[x,t]-u, 
  V[x, 0] == v, U[x, 0] == u}
NDSolve[System, {U[x, t], V[x, t]}, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

Plotting wont be much of an issue as instead of a manipulate plot, those constants will just be given values in the actual equations later.

The second code is as from the link here on stack exchange

```
r0 = First@
   Solve[{z[x, t] == u[x, t] - v[x, t], 
     y[x, t] == u[x, t] + v[x, t] }, {u[x, t], v[x, t]}];
eq1 = (Unevaluated[
      a D[u[x, t], t] - b D[u[x, t], x, x] - c v[x, t] + 
       Exp[1/u[x, t]]] /. %) // Simplify;
eq2 = (Unevaluated[
      d D[v[x, t], t] + e D[v[x, t], x] - f D[v[x, t], x, x] - 
       g v[x, t] Exp[1/ u[x, t]]] /. %%) // Simplify;
Simplify[eq1 - eq2];
r1 = Simplify[#] & /@ DSolve[% == 0, z[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]]
Simplify[eq1 + eq2 ];
r2 = Simplify[#] & /@ DSolve[% == 0, y[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]] /. 
  C[1] -> C[2]
r0 /. {r1, r2}
```

Not only does the above code confuse me, but I have no idea how I will plot the functions nor do I know how to incorporate my boundary conditions. But the main issue with this code is I don't understand the mathematica commands and method used, so ideally my code (if possible) would be better to edit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Ken

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Issue 1:** You get the error

> NDSolve : Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in
>   the first argument

because, e.g., `D[V[1, t], x]` returns `0` and `System` contains equations of the form `D[V[1, t], x] == 0` which evaluates to `True`. See, `V[1, t]` does really not depend on `x`. What you *mean* is `D[V[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0` where you may read `/. x -> 0` as "at $x = 0$".

The cleaned up `System` looks like this:

```
System = {
  a D[U[x, t], t] == b D[U[x, t], x, x] + c V[x, t] Exp[-1/U[x, t]], 
  d D[V[x, t], t] + e D[V[x, t], x] == f D[V[x, t], x, x] - g V[x, t] Exp[-1/U[x, t]],
  D[V[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0,
  D[V[x, t], x] == V[x, t] - v /. x -> 1,
  D[U[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0,
  D[U[x, t], x] == U[x, t] - u /. x -> 1,
  V[x, 0] == v,
  U[x, 0] == u
  }
```

**Issue 2:** It should be something like

```
  NDSolve[System, {U[x, t], V[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

since otherwise, the spacial boundary is not the boundary.

**Issue 3:** Using `NDSolve` with symbols appearing in the equations is futile. But after setting them to numeric values, it works just fine:

```
ClearAll[U, V]
a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; e = 1; f = 1; g = 1;
v = 6; u = 4;
System = {
   a D[U[x, t], t] == b D[U[x, t], x, x] + c V[x, t] Exp[-1/U[x, t]], 
   d D[V[x, t], t] + e D[V[x, t], x] == f D[V[x, t], x, x] - g V[x, t] Exp[-1/U[x, t]],
   D[V[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0,
   D[V[x, t], x] == V[x, t] - v /. x -> 1,
   D[U[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0,
   D[U[x, t], x] == U[x, t] - u /. x -> 1,
   V[x, 0] == v,
   U[x, 0] == u
   };
{U, V} = NDSolveValue[System, {U, V}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}]

Plot3D[{U[x, t], V[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate you explaining the errors. This way I can see what corrections I need to make in future if I encounter them again. I also forgot about the /.-> so that's something I definitely need to keep in mind while approaching these types of problems. Many thanks Henrik

Comment: KennyB, you're always welcome!