# Solving multi-field problems in MMA 11.3

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

Based on the PDE model proposed by @Schumacher [Solving a second order coupled PDE system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163867/solving-a-second-order-coupled-pde-system?rq=1), the ***one dimensional multi-field Problem*** I would like to solve such benchmark test:

namely:

> **u(x)**: displacement
>
> **s(x)**: diffusive parameter:

Strong forms:

$0=s^{2} E u^{\prime\prime}$

$0=s E (u^{\prime})^{2}-\mathcal{G}_{c}\left(2 \epsilon s^{\prime \prime}+\frac{1-s}{2 \epsilon}\right)$

BCs:

$u(x=\pm L)=\pm u_{0}$

$s^{\prime}( \pm L)=0$

(Optimal:$s( \pm L)=1$)

and

> Initial Value for s(x)=1;
>
> $s \in[0,1]$;

My code looks like:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
PDE1 = (s[x])^2 u''[x] == 0
PDE2 = 2 ϵ s''[x] + 0.5 (1 - s[x])/ϵ - 
   s[x] Ε (u'[x])^2/\[ScriptCapitalG] == 0

lr = 25;
ll = -25;
Ε = 1;
 \[ScriptCapitalG] = 1;
u0 = 10;
ϵ = 0.125;
ics = {u[ll] == -u0, u[lr] == u0, s'[ll] == 0, s'[lr] == 0, 
  s[ll] == 1, s[lr] == 1}
{uu,vv} = NDSolve[{PDE1, PDE2, ics}, {u, s}, {x, ll, lr}]
```

This code cannot run due to **initial BCs problems in MMA**.

DSolve also not possible in MMA:

> DSolve::argm: DSolve called with 2 arguments; 3 or more arguments are
>   expected.

Okay, then I have the following questions:

> 1. can we solve this nonlinear problem in MMA11.3?
> 2. how can we fix BCs in MMA, it should works? it seems not that difficult.
> 3. can we use fdm or spectral method for NDsolve, or we have to use fem here?
> 4. which numerical method is mostly recommonded for this problem (robust and efficient) for version 11.3?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a system of two second order elliptic equations. You can only apply $2 \times 2$ boundary conditions: two for each elliptic equation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  hey, thanks, in this case, I would like to get inhomogeneous solution, therefore I add two additional at the end of bar.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher moreover, if I use the first four BCs, then I got the errors:NDSolve::berr: The scaled boundary value residual error of 4.948245340445189`*^77 indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found.

Comment: This returns _something_, but I don't want to decide whether it is meaningful: `sol = NDSolveValue[{PDE1, PDE2, ics[[{1, 2, 5, 6}]]}, {u, s},
  x \[Element] 
   DiscretizeRegion[Line[{{ll}, {lr}}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
  ]`

Comment: The problem is that the first PDE is quite degenerated where `s` vanishes.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher sure ... but okay, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97749/discussion-between-abcdemmm-and-henrik-schumacher).

Comment: By "inhomogeneous solution" do you mean non-trivial solution i.e. solution that's not constant?

Comment: @xzczd sometime we can get such a localized solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "localized solution"?

Comment: The whole life I work with Ginzburg-Landau equation, but have never seen it in this form. Even more, I do not see nonlinearity in it. Could you please kindly comment, why do you call these equations Ginzburg-Landau?

Answer (score 3):

The  method of the false transient works well to solve this problem. The solution quickly converges with an increase in the number of iterations `t`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
PDE1 = (s[t, x])^2 D[u[t, x], x, x] == D[u[t, x], t];
PDE2 = 2 \[Epsilon] D[s[t, x], x, x] + 0.5 (1 - s[t, x])/\[Epsilon] - 
    s[t, x] \[CapitalEpsilon]1 (D[u[t, x], x])^2/\[ScriptCapitalG] == 
   D[s[t, x], t];

lr = 25;
ll = -25;
\[CapitalEpsilon]1 = 1;
\[ScriptCapitalG] = 1;
u0 = 10;
\[Epsilon] = 0.125;
bcs1 = {u[t, ll] == -u0, u[t, lr] == u0};
bcs2 = {s[t, ll] == 1, s[t, lr] == 1};
bcs3 = {Derivative[0, 1][s][t, ll] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][s][t, lr] == 0};
ic = {u[0, x] == u0  x/lr, s[0, x] == 1};
{uu, vv} = 
 NDSolveValue[{PDE1, PDE2, bcs1, bcs2, ic}, {u, s}, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 
   0, 10}]

{Plot3D[uu[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[vv[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
{Plot[uu[10, x], {x, ll, lr}], 
 Plot[vv[10, x], {x, ll, lr}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
If you use the Newman condition, then the solution will be

```
{uu1, vv1} = 
 NDSolveValue[{PDE1, PDE2, bcs1, bcs3, ic}, {u, s}, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 
   0, 10}]

{Plot3D[uu1[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[vv1[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: why we use u[0, x] == u0 x/lr as boundary condition?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM These are initial data, not boundary conditions. I took this to agree with the boundary conditions.

Comment: I donot define such initial value in the benchmark test.

Comment: we donot use any body loading. just the displacement at the end of bar.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Firstly, you did not solve this problem. Therefore, it is impossible to call this a benchmark test. Secondly, when solving by the method that I proposed, it is necessary to set the initial conditions (in fact, this is the initial approximation to the solution). You can choose any initial conditions. I chose the ones that I liked.

Comment: can we define u[0, x] == 0 ? or we must define u[0, x] == u0  x/lr (none zero initial value)?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Condition `u[0,x]==0` certainly does not fit, because it is not consistent with the boundary conditions `bcs1 = {u[t, ll] == -u0, u[t, lr] == u0};`.

Comment: if we use transient load: i.e., bcs1 = {u[t, ll] == -u0 t, u[t, lr] == u0 t} then can we use Condition u[0,x]==0 ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM What does this have to do with the Ginzburg-Landau equation?

Comment: I have modified the title.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM OK! What does this have to do with the system of equations that you want to solve? I showed you the solution method. But to investigate this method in different cases is not included in my plans. Sorry, I'm very busy.